# Inserting Table Records to another table from two different Instance

Tags: sql

I have Two Same table that they are not in same instance or server ,one of them is "mssqlfaranam" and the other one is my local Instance. in both of theme  i have tblBlackList .but in one of theme is data and the other one is not . how can i Insert to "Local database" table from   "mssqlfaranm". both instance are sql server 2008

Comment: Is this SQL Server? You could use Replication, or set up Linked Servers.

Comment: no . i have two table in different server i want insert data to another one . like "Insert Into #[table] from [table]"

Comment: But are your 2 different instances both MS SQL Server? Please add this information to your question. Also, this might be helpful: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19095/what-options-exist-for-copying-data-between-servers-on-a-regular-basis

Comment: You can do that using a [linked server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

Comment: is there any query ? and can you say as awnser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Import and Export Data` wizard.

`DROP` the table in the local before performing the following steps.

### **STEP 1 :**

**Choose a Data Source**

Select `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` from the dropdownlist for Data Source.
Then Select `Use SQL Server Authentication`.
Enter the `Server name`, `User name` and `Password`.
Then Select the `Database` from the dropdownlist.
Then Click `Next`.

---

### **STEP 2 :**

**Choose a Destination**

Select `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` from the dropdownlist for Data Source.
Then Select `Use SQL Server Authentication` or `Use Windows Authentication` as per your requirement.
Enter the `User name` and `Password`.
Then Select the `Database` from the dropdownlist.
Then Click `Next`.

---

### **STEP 3 :**

**Specify Table Copy or Query**

Select `Copy data from one or more tables or views`.
Then Click `Next`.

---

### **STEP 4 :**

**Select Source Tables and Views**

Check the table which you want to copy.
Then Click `Next`

---

### **STEP 5 :**

**Save and Run Package**

Check `Run Immediately`
Then Click `Next`

---

### **STEP 6 :**

**Complete the wizard**

Click `Finish` button.

After the execution, it will show a success message if success or error message if there is any error.
Close the wizard.